# What is the size in memory of a Clojure keyword?

Tags: java, memory, clojure

I'm writing a function in Clojure to estimate the in-memory size of a parsed JSON, something like:

```
(defn object-size
  [object]
  (cond
    (sequential? object)
      (reduce + (map object-size object))
    (map? object)
      (reduce
        (fn [total [k v]]
          (+ total (keyword-size k) (object-size v)))
        0
        object)
    :else
      (case (type object)
        java.lang.Long 8 
        java.lang.Double 8
        java.lang.String (* 2 (count object))
        ;; other data types
      )))
```

Obviously I'll need to add in overheads for `clojure.lang.PersistentVector`, `java.lang.String`, etc.

However, I'm not sure how to find the in-memory size of a `clojure.lang.Keyword`, the `keyword-size` function in the above example.  How does Clojure store keywords?  Are they constant size similar to a C++ `enum`, or are they a special case of `java.lang.String` that are dependent on length?

Comment: For strings you would have to take into account which Java version you run. Java 9 has optimization for the string memory AFAIK.
Good question otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this question from within Clojure is basically impossible. Your first-draft function works *okay* for the very simplest data structures, although even this simplest attempt has several errors already.

But more than that, it is just an ill-framed question. What is the size of `xs` in this snippet?

```
(def xs (let [forever (promise)]
          (deliver forever
                   (lazy-seq (cons 1 @forever)))
          @forever))

user=> (take 5 xs)
(1 1 1 1 1)
```

`xs` is an infinitely long sequence (so your reduce will never complete, but if it could it would surely return "this is infinite"). But it actually takes a small, fixed amount of memory, because it is circular.

You may say, well gee this is a dumb object, I don't mind if my function fails for objects like that. But in a garbage-collected language with pervasive laziness, cases with similar characteristics are commonplace. If you rule them out, you rule out everything interesting.

Comment: The use case here is for parsed stats JSONs from Youtube, Twitter, etc, which will always be fairly simple.  We partition these stats into batches for processing and need to get an idea of how large the batches can be for a given heap size (which isn't very interesting).  I agree that this approach makes no sense for anything but the simplest structures, but those are all that we need it for.

Comment: If you only need a very rough estimate for the size of a JSON structure, just take the size of the JSON string itself. If you want to know how many objects you can fit in memory for a given heap size, *try it* with various batch sizes and see which ones succeed. The size of one particular subset of items on the heap is not going to correlate very cleanly.